# Wordpress PHP 404 page is not returning

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

When I search for something in the search query, WordPress returns a blank page instead of the 404.php page, but I don't know why... if code needed, i'll show.

Comment: I would try disabling all plugins. If it still happens, re-enable then until you zero in on the culprit.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more info, it's tough to say, but searching should NEVER return a 404 page. Why it shows a blank page is a different question -- most likely because you don't have a template page created for search results (search.php)